# Show that a set is one reducible to another given its m-reducible

Tags: logic, computability, automata

A set $A$ is a cylinder if there is a set $B$ such that A  $\equiv_1$ B x N.
Show that if S is a cylinder, then for any set C: C  $\le_m$ S => C  $\le_1$ S

**My Approach :** 
Since S is a cylinder therefore there exists a set S2 such that S $\equiv_1$ S2 x N.
What I understand by m reducibility is that the function will be many to one. Whereas in 
1 reducibility the function will be one-to-one. I am not sure if I am interpreting the definition 
correctly. To produce a one-to-one function seems difficult with this definition.

Let $f1$ be function for S  $\le_1$ S2 x N and $f2$ for  S2 x N $\le_m$ S 
consider the function $f2(f1(x))$ this is a one-one mapping from S to S 
I am wondering if it could somehow be converted to a mapping from C to S 
I have a feeling this question is not difficult but I am missing something

Any hints or pointers to this ?